# how to load millions rows, little by little with ajax in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Seeing datatables I cannot achieve this goal. For now I can load them in different ways, with ajax (by using the server side) different rows and with different orders, but for now I cannot load rows for example in 4 or 5 times making multiple request ajax ( I want to use the scroll to load little by little).

How could I do this?

Comment: Well, for one, you'd never want millions of rows to exist on the page at any one time, therefore you'll never want to load more rows without first removing the previous rows. I'd suggest using datatables + server-side pagination, in that when the user clicks "Next Page" or "Previous Page", the contents of the table are replaced with a new set of rows from the server, whether they come from an ajax request or from a full page reload.

Comment: As @Kevin Said I would go with pagination from server side

Comment: OK, is logic what you say, but that mean that we cannot load them little by little?

Comment: atm i speculate about off-the-cuff performance gaps if you do server side pagination with sorting for X users with one million entities ;)

Comment: well, im not using 1 million of rows, actually quite a lot less, but was to make me understand when I was asking this. But jum......I dont want pagination, seems a limitation for the design I have to do (my client doesnt want pagination, want scroll).

Answer (score 3):

What about modifying your ajax to load x number of rows, starting with the first, then when the top offset of the last entry comes into view you could fire another ajax event on the same file, but use x to know what the last row was to be loaded so it will know which row to start loading from?

So say it loads rows 0-5 initially, and when 5 comes into view, it fires an event that would pass through the same ajax but with the value 5, so it would start from 6 and load the next 6 rows, and so on You would be able to use the same function for the initial and following loads, it would just get appended to the html of the main element.

**EDIT**
Okay, so we'll need a php file that pulls and formats the data, and an html file that contains the ajax and displays everything.

for the php, something like:

```
$offset = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 20, ".$offset;
```

Then run a loop to format the rows how you would like them to be.

This will populate the page initially with 20 posts from the offset, which is 0 by default.

Then for the Ajax, there're two parts. First is create an action when the last item comes into view:

```
var go = true;
function hitbottom() {
    var sh = $(window).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var ih = $('.item').last().offset().top;
    if ((sh+wh)<ih && go) {
        //run ajax
    }
}
```

This should be run on scroll to trigger when the top of the last item hits the bottom of the screen.

The second is to create the ajax form, which needs to know the id of the last row shown. It will use that value to change the value of the offset variable in the php file, which will then get the next 20 rows and send them back to jquery to append to the html in the callback, and so on...

The ajax part should set go to false, then set it back to true on the callback to start it all over again.

To append the data, you can use something like this:

```
$('#element').append(data);
```

This is untested, and just an idea. I would imagine it's similar to how your facebook feed loads. Once you hit the bottom it pops up the loading icon, and loads the next set of posts. Only with this, it will begin loading just before you hit the bottom, so unless you jet down right away, it should be able to pull the new data pretty quickly.

This also allows you to gradually increase the html file content, without loading a lot of content at once and slowing things down. There may still be a limit, but it should be pretty large.

Comment: I want that exactly, but I dont know how to trigger the request ajax with datatables, I just fired the first time (by default, is automatic). And even If I fire it, I dont know how to append the data in the reply. May you give me a clue?

Comment: I updated the initial answer with the main parts. Do a search for how to pass variable to php file with ajax on form submit, then you can get the new offset by getting a count of the rows listed currently on the page and subtracting 1, and pass that to the php file for the next set of results.